# Multiplying several numbers within a text string, is this possible?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regexextract

I have cell A1 which is a text string:

```
100 blue cars, 100 red cars, 100 yellow cars
```

In cell B1 I have a number which is a multiplier say `2`.

Is it possible to change the numbers within cell A1 dependant on the value in B1.

Eg.

```
A1: 300 blue cars, 300 red cars, 300 yellow cars

B1: 3
```

Comment: You should edit this question and explain *how* you want to multiply ("in cell" or "from cell to cell")

Answer (score -1):

```
=100*B1&" blue cars, "&100*B1&" red cars, "&100*B1&" yellow cars"
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, ","), "\d+") * B1&
                                REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(A1, ","), "\d+(.*)")))
```

[image: 0]